# Symbolic conditional sum

Tags: python, sum, sympy, symbolic-math

Is there a way to calculate, or at least state properly, a symbolic sum which iterates over a sequence conditionally?

For example, if `a(n)` is a sequence (of reals) and `c(n)` is a "condition" (boolean function defined on the integers), then I wish to compute, or at least state, the sum over all `a(n)`'s for which `c(n)`.

Formally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
n = Symbol('n', integer=True, positive=True)
a = 1 / n**2
c = Eq(n%3, 1)
## s = Sum(a, (n, 0, oo), condition=c)
```

So `s` should be the following sum:

```
1/1 + 1/16 + 1/49 + 1/100 + 1/169 + ...
```

Of course, in this case I can define `s` manually, but I wonder whether I can do it automatically somehow.

### Edit:

By *manually* I mean

```
Sum(1/(3*n+1)**2, (n, 0, oo))
```

This can be evaluated (and it is about `1.12173301393634`).

An attempt I've made (which failed) is as follows:

```
Sum(Eq(n%3, 1) * (1/n**2), (n, 0, oo))
```

Trying to evaluate this using `.evalf()` resulted

```
AttributeError: 'BooleanFalse' object has no attribute '_eval_evalf'
```

### Edit (2):

Here's another attempt, which yields a wrong result:

```
p = Piecewise((1/(n**2), Eq(n%3, 1)), (0, True))
Sum(p, (n, 0, oo)).evalf()
## returns 1.00000000000000
```

Either I've done something wrong, or this is a sympy bug.

Comment: I don't know any of predefined functions which can do what you have asked for but you can write one function for yourself. :)

Comment: UNTESTED `a = 1 / n**2 if Eq(n%3, 1) else 0` ps: of course it depends on when the `if` `else` is executed...

Comment: Well, a function which is 1 if `c(n)` and 0 otherwise is generally called an "indicator function". So your summation can be expressed as `Sum(I(n)*a(n), n, 1, oo)` where `I(n)` is the indicator function. I don't know if it helps, but anyway that's the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Piecewise is definitely the correct way to do this. The wrong result is a bug in SymPy, which you should report at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new.  Your second method won't work because in SymPy booleans are not implicitly integers (True and False are not 1 and 0).

Comment: As discussed at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8321#issuecomment-62160736 it is probably not a good idea to use Piecewise with a 0 condition. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6756#issuecomment-62243662 for a helper function xSum that allows extended interpretation of the limit to handle the change of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Or avoid piecewise by defining your function as 1/(3*n+1)**2

```
>>> Sum((3*n + 1)**(-2), (n, 0, oo))
Sum((3*n + 1)**(-2), (n, 0, oo))
>>> print filldedent(_.doit())

exp(-4*I*pi/3)*polylog(2, exp_polar(4*I*pi/3))/3 + pi**2/18 +
exp(-2*I*pi/3)*polylog(2, exp_polar(2*I*pi/3))/3
>>> Sum((3*n + 1)**(-2), (n, 0, oo)).n()
1.12173301393634
```

You can see that the remapping works by using Symbol-trickery. e.g. the 1st 6 terms:

```
>>> Add(*[(1/n).subs(n,Symbol(str((3*i+1)**2))) for i in range(5)])
1/49 + 1/169 + 1/16 + 1/100 + 1/1
```

Comment: Indeed, I can do that; that's what I meant when I said "manually"; but I wish to avoid that in general, as I am looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a linear sequence then you could use Integal's transform method to do the transformation for you:

```
>>> i=Integral(1/x**2,(x,1,oo))
>>> i.transform(x,3*x - 2)
Integral(3/(3*x - 2)**2, (x, 1, oo))
>>> (Sum(*_.args)/3).n(3)  # divide by 3 to handle renorm
1.12
```